# Flow, pulling from "apply to each" versus simple compose statements

Tags: power-automate

I'm populating a word document among other pieces and I'm having trouble with data from within an "apply to each".  With the "apply to each" I have a compose statement.

For my "compose" components not nested in the "apply to each", I use the following without issue.

outputs('Compose_company')?['value']?[0]?['Company_Name']

Any thoughts on how I pull from the "apply to each"?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Can you show us the section of your flow you're having problems with (via screenshot) and be specific as to what your issue is?

Answer (score 0):

when you are inside an "Apply to Each" action, you select an array/collection that will be used to apply the logic to each item.

So, if the Compose you use outside of the "apply to each" is

```
outputs('Compose_company')?['value']?[0]?['Company_Name']
```

This means that in the "apply to each" action you will pass

```
outputs('Compose_company')?['value']
```

and it will look like this

[image: Apply to each parameter]

You see that I have renamed my "Apply to each" to "My cycle", so when I want to compose something with this example, it will be

```
items('My_cycle')?['Company_Name']
```

or

```
item()?['Company_Name']
```

The difference is that items() requires the name of the iteration you want, and item() gets the item from the current scope it is in.

Please let me know if I understood your question and if this helps.

Best regards